# Rails 3.0.3 and Polyglot Gem problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, polyglot

I hope you can help me.

I had a rails app running locally, and also uploaded and running on Heroku.  All was well.  Last week, I started work again and ran into a snag.

At the beginning of my day, I opened up Terminal and ran 'rails s' to start the local server.  I received this error:

doug-naegeles-macbook-pro-17:elig_check dougnaegele$ rails s
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:129:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'polyglot', required by 'rails (= 3.0.3)', in any of the sources (Bundler::VersionConflict)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in`catch'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `resolve'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:151:in`resolve'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:135:in`specs_for'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:124:in `requested_specs'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in`requested_specs'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:100:in`setup'
 from /Users/dougnaegele/Sites/elig_check/config/boot.rb:8
 from script/rails:5:in `require'
 from script/rails:5

---

When I run 'gem list'..i can see Polyglot listed:

doug-naegeles-macbook-pro-17:elig_check dougnaegele$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.3, 2.3.5, 2.2.2, 1.3.6)
actionpack (3.0.3, 2.3.5, 2.2.2, 1.13.6)
actionwebservice (1.2.6)
activemodel (3.0.3)
activerecord (3.0.3, 2.3.5, 2.2.2, 1.15.6)
activeresource (3.0.3, 2.3.5, 2.2.2)
activesupport (3.0.3, 2.3.5, 2.2.2, 1.4.4)
acts_as_ferret (0.5.2, 0.4.3)
arel (2.0.6, 2.0.4)
authlogic (2.1.6)
blythedunham-sms_on_rails (0.1.0)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.7)
capistrano (2.5.19, 2.5.2)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
color (1.4.1)
configuration (1.2.0)
crack (0.1.8)
daemons (1.1.0, 1.0.10)
derailed-ziya (2.1.5)
dnssd (1.4, 0.6.0)
erubis (2.6.6)
fastthread (1.0.7, 1.0.1)
fcgi (0.8.8, 0.8.7)
ferret (0.11.6)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
googlecharts (1.6.0)
heroku (1.14.10, 1.14.3)
highline (1.6.1, 1.5.0)
hpricot (0.8.3, 0.6.164)
httparty (0.6.1)
i18n (0.5.0, 0.4.2)
jk-ferret (0.11.8.2)
json_pure (1.4.6)
launchy (0.3.7)
libxml-ruby (1.1.4, 1.1.2)
little-plugger (1.1.2)
logging (1.4.3)
mail (2.2.12, 2.2.10)
mattetti-googlecharts (1.4.0)
mime-types (1.16)
mongrel (1.1.5)
mysql (2.8.1)
needle (1.3.0)
net-scp (1.0.4, 1.0.1)
net-sftp (2.0.5, 2.0.1, 1.1.1)
net-ssh (2.0.23, 2.0.4, 1.1.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.0.1, 1.0.0)
nifty-generators (0.4.2)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1, 1.0.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.6)
rails (3.0.3, 2.3.5, 2.2.2, 1.2.6)
railties (3.0.3)
rake (0.8.7, 0.8.3)
RedCloth (4.2.3, 4.1.1)
rest-client (1.6.1)
ruby-openid (2.1.8, 2.1.2)
ruby-yadis (0.3.4)
rubygems-update (1.3.7, 1.3.6)
rubynode (0.1.5)
sequel (3.18.0, 3.17.0)
sinatra (1.1.0, 1.0)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2, 1.2.5, 1.2.4)
static_record_cache (0.2.0)
taps (0.3.14)
termios (0.9.4)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.1)
treetop (1.4.9)
twilio (2.9.0)
twiliolib (2.0.7)
tzinfo (0.3.23)
xmpp4r (0.5, 0.4)

---

When I run 'gem sources' I get this:

doug-naegeles-macbook-pro-17:elig_check dougnaegele$ gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

rubygems.org/
gems.github.com
gems.github.com
gems.github.com/
gems.github.com
gems.rubyforge.org

Which looks right -- that's where Polyglot lives.

---

When I run 'bundle install' I get this:

doug-naegeles-macbook-pro-17:elig_check dougnaegele$ bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'polyglot', required by 'rails (= 3.0.3)', in any of the sources

---

Any idea?  I've tried to reinstall the gem, run 'bundle install' etc.  No luck.

(I have a suspicion that this -> rails (3.0.3, 2.3.5, 2.2.2, 1.2.6) may be the problem, but I don't want to go down that road just yet.  I have apps running on 2.3.5 that have not been refactored for rails 3.0)

Thanks in advance!
Doug

Comment: RVM and project specific gemsets might be your rescue. You can get automatic gemset switching too with .rvmrc. http://everydayrails.com/2010/09/13/rvm-project-gemsets.html

Comment: Hi..Im the original asker.  If it helps, in my Gemfile I changed rails 3.0.3 to rails 3.0.0 and redid 'bundle install'.  Everything works now.  Punting the problem until later.  thx.

Answer (score 0):

OP from comments above:

> If it helps, in my Gemfile I changed rails 3.0.3 to rails 3.0.0 and
>   redid 'bundle install'. Everything works now. Punting the problem
>   until later.